# Syntax error in Python... I dont understand why

Tags: python, class, syntax

I'm making a program that reads numbers and names from a file and turns them into Person objects. Its methods should be able to display a name or number, or all peoples' names and numbers. But for some reason i'm getting stuck in my Environment class with a syntax error where i'm increasing y at 'y+=2' in the while loop inside the populate method.

```
class Person (object):
pplCnt = 0
def __init__ (self,name,number):
    print("Creating a person named ", name, ", phone number: ", number)
    self.name = name
    self.number = number
    Person.pplCnt+=1
def getName(self):
    return self.name
def getNum(self):
    return self.number
def getAmtPpl(self):
    return Person.pplCnt

class Environtment:
x=0
y=0
def __init__(self):
    self.pplList = []
def populate(self):
    people = open("names.txt","r")
    listof = []
    for line in people:
        listof.append(line)
        x+=1
    while y<=x:
        self.pplList.append(Person(listof[y],listof[y+1])
        y+=2

def nameAll(self):
    z=0
    while z < int(x/2):
        print("Name: ",self.pplList[z].getName(),"\nNumber: ",self.pplList[z].getNum(),"\n")
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: just edited that, its in the description

Comment: I assume the indentation errors are a result of copy/paste into stack overflow?

Comment: yep indentation is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're missing a parenthesis

```
self.pplList.append(Person(listof[y],listof[y+1])
```

99% of strange syntax errors are caused by an unclosed parenthesis on the line above because python is trying to do a line continuation which then makes for the syntax error.  After all, we don't expect

```
self.pplList.append(Person(listof[y],listof[y+1])y+=2
```

to be proper syntax.

Comment: that explains a lot! thanks!